# Characterization of local rings

Tags: ring-theory

Local rings are often characterized as rings that have the property that for every element x, either x or 1 − x is a unit.

This is equivalent to saying that for every element x, either x or 1 + x is a unit. The characterization in terms of addition seems more intuitive to me. Is there any reason that everyone seems to prefer the subtraction characterization?

Answer (score 3):

Because $x + (1 - x) = 1$ so if $x \in \mathfrak{m}$ and $1 - x \in \mathfrak{m}$ then $1 \in \mathfrak{m}$ (which would be a contradiction). The addition happens between $x$ and $1 - x$ rather than between $x$ and $1$.

Two other reasons are that $x \mapsto 1 - x$ is an involution and that the formula for $(1 - x)^{-1}$ (say in a complete local ring) is much nicer:

$$ \frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots.$$

Comment: One could just as well say that $1 = (1+x)-x$, so that if $x\in\mathfrak{m}$ and $1+x\in\mathfrak{m}$ then $1\in\mathfrak{m}$....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I said the addition happens between $1 - x$ and $x$ rather than between $1$ and $x$. Obviously it's just a matter of taste and doesn't affect any of the proofs.

Comment: Yes; but the OP is precisely asking why is it that almost everyone’s taste seems to be to use $1-x$ rather than $1+x$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The partition of unity reason seems like a fine reason to me. I've added two more reasons but I can't speak for anyone else's taste but my self.